# can't understand one of the steps in harris operator math equation

Tags: matrix, computer-vision, corner-detection

So I was reading a lecture note on corner detection and I just can't figure out a step in the math equation
[image]

how do you turn the above equation into the below one? Thank you

Comment: Did you want [math.se]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, yes. I suppose I should've posted in maths, I just thought since this is a cs problem, maybe someone has already tackled on the issue and got an answer.

Comment: There is also [cs.se], SO is for more practical programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

All the summed pieces look like: multiply the matrix to get ((I sub x)u+I(sub y)v). 
((I sub x)u+I(sub y)v)^2=((I sub x)u+I(sub y)v)((I sub x)u+I(sub y)v)=(I sub x)^2(u^2)+(I sub x)u(Isuby)v+(I sub y)v(Isub x)u+(I sub y)^2v^2.

On the other hand, if you look at the last two terms getting multiplied in the second line, your first row looks like ((I sub x)^2)u+(Isubx)(Isuby)v and your second row looks like (I sub x)(I sub y)u+((I sub y)^2)v. Multiple that on the left by [u, v] and you have u((I sub x)^2)u+u(I sub x)(I sub y)v+v(I sub x)(I sub y)u+v((Isub y)^2)v, which should be rearrangeable  to the last line of my preceding paragraph. I am being a little sloppy here with some assumptions about what can commute in the multiplications, but this should be the gist.